# El filtro de fecha en Telerik (vs2013) no funciona correctamente

Tags: date, visual-studio-2013, filtro, telerik

uso Telerik en VS 2013. En el designer hago esto:
Propiedades > ReportParameters > Type: DateTime Visible: True
Propiedades > Filters > Add > en Expression =Trim(Fields.Date) en Operator = en Value =Fields.Date

Pero cuando le doy preview y escojo una fecha, todos los registros aparecen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución estaba en que había que poner un valor en Value y usar string, no date. La fecha había que introducirla a mano, porque con el datepicker no funcionaba.